# How to handle rails3 habtm with tree hierarchy (of categories)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tree, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've looked at the existing questions and because of variations, I cannot find a good solution on how to handle habtm with a tree hierarchy of categories. acts-as-taggable-on imposes that the code knows the contexts, which I do not want. This has been asked several times on this and other websites but truly, there has not been a complete answer yet.

Basically I have a set of categories with a single-level hierarchy:

- Root category 1

  - Sub category 3
  - Sub category 4
- Root category 2

  - Sub category 5
  - Sub category 6

The form part is somewhat simpler. I list all the root categories, then for each find the children. This is suitable only for single level hierarchy, and not optimal for my needs since I would rather have near infinite level (i.e. a solution that is indifferent to nesting level), although not necessary if it adds too much complexity.

It's mostly on the view that I am not sure how to proceed. At this point I can get a simple hash of the associated categories, but there is no hierarchy. Nested categories solutions I have seen will not work in the habtm context, rather working with the full tree itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well it was not so obvious but Ancestry (aka has_ancestry: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) manages that very well.

My model has products with categories in a HABTM relationship. The categories are a hierarchy with has_ancestry.

Once I get the product's categories, it's a simple matter of calling arrange on the collection:

> @product.categories.arrange.each do |root_cats, sub_cats|

Works marvellously.

So in short, the anwer is the Ancestry gem: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry.